# using struts 2 action for a simple ajax request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I am trying to make a simple request using AJAX . But the whole thing is not working. Below is the code I wrote

jsp/javascript :

```
$("#my_"+rowNum).load("getdata.action?id="+123,function(data) {
       alert("i am inside "+data);
});
```

Struts Action :

```
public class MyAction extends BaseAction {

    public String execute() {
       try  {
         inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("ABC 123 556".getBytes("UTF-8"));
       }
       catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          //handle exception
       }
       return SUCCESS;
    }
}​
```

struts.xml :

```
<action name="getdata" class="com.amtd.advisoradmin.action.MyAction">
 <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
 </result>
```

I feel the configuration is correct, but I don't get the alert I printed in my jsp after the control returns from the Action class. Am I missing something ?

PS : ABC 123 556 is the data I need to get in the alerts.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you stream the data and don't just return it JSON encoded, for example? What do you get when you call that action yourself, i.e. directly from the browser?

Comment: I am just returning a single piece of text. So I decided not to return as a json. The control is going and returning normally from the Action class.

Comment: Well, it should be possible to return the text as is. In that case it would just be treated like HTML would. I'd rather try and keep things simple without adding the extra complexity of stream results etc. Btw, why don't you use jQuery's `ajax` function?

Comment: `inputStream` is more for the download perspective not a typical example for Ajax and yes it can be done with simple Jquery.

Comment: @Thomas  How do you keep the text as is?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: I wrote inputstream because it was in the strtus documentation.

Comment: @user2434 just use another result type. Besides that, there are struts2 plugins for JSON and even AJAX support, so why not just use them?

Comment: @user2434: i know about that but its like very early example and it was not valid example.

Comment: @user2434 What are you trying to achieve here. Do you want to display an image on a jsp?

Comment: No. I just want to send a string. That's all.

Comment: I've added a note to the latest S2 wiki indicating that using a stream result is not really the preferred mechanism; thanks @UmeshAwasthi.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a private variable for inputStream type InputStream and public getter and setter for it in your Action class, which is missing.

Thanks